# kubernetes persistent volume for bare metal accessible on all nodes and pods

Tags: kubernetes

I was trying the local or host path volumes on a LAN bare metal servers.

tried local but each node was having there own copy of the data.

How can i use volumes across all the nodes and pods.

Answer (score 1):

Persistent Volumes have access semantics. Example on GCE if you are using a Persistent Disk, can either be mounted as writable to a single pod or to multiple pods as read-only. If you want multi writer semantics, you need to setup NFS or some other storage that let's you write from multiple pods. NFS can support multiple read/write clients.

In case you are interested in running NFS take a look: [nfs-setup](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.2/examples/nfs/README.md).

The NFS persistent volume and NFS claim gives an indirection that allow multiple pods to refer to the NFS server using a symbolic name rather than the hardcoded server address.

Take a look: [pv-multiple-pods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36506791/how-do-i-make-a-persistent-volume-accessible-to-multiple-kubernetes-pods).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share data through your cluster, then you need to use network storage.
You can't expect kubernetes to just share your data accross all the nodes of your cluster. So local storage and host path won't work in that case.

As @MaggieO said, you can setup and use a NFS server.
If you just want to try it out, you can also use your favorite cloud provider storage solution (AWS S3, GCP Bucket, Azure Disk, etc). You can see the full list [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#types-of-persistent-volumes)